# Use a sequence of write() instead a single write()

Tags: c, unix, atomic

I'm programming in C on a Unix system. I know that:

```
write(fd,"ABCD",4);
```

is better than do that:

```
write(fd, "A", 1);
write(fd, "B", 1);
write(fd, "C", 1);
write(fd, "D", 1);
```

Obviously, I'm **not** talking about code legibility, but I want to know what problems the second methodology could give. Do we talk about the atomicity of execution? If yes why?

Thanks

Comment: "what problems the second methodology could give"  The 2nd (and 1st) do not check the return value of `write()`.  Robust code would do so.

Comment: Note that in most cases where you need atomicity, you would get it by file locking rather than trying to rely on structuring the `write` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to be worried about atomicity here.

If another process, or another thread within the same process, is also writing to the same communications channel, then

```
write(fd, "ABCD", 4);
```

will write the four bytes "ABCD" atomically, in the sense that output from the other writers cannot appear in the middle of those four bytes.  On the other hand,

```
write(fd, "A", 1);
write(fd, "B", 1);
write(fd, "C", 1);
write(fd, "D", 1);
```

will write each byte separately, and output from the other writers *can* appear in between the letters.

However, atomicity is only guaranteed for *short* writes, where the third argument is smaller than the constant `PIPE_BUF`.  If you write more data than that, there is no way to ensure that output from other writers doesn't appear in the middle.  `PIPE_BUF` may be as small as 512 but is usually somewhat larger than that nowadays.

The easiest way to see this for yourself is with `fork` and writes to standard output:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;

    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        write(1, "ABCD", 4);  sleep(1);
        write(1, "A", 1);     sleep(1);
        write(1, "B", 1);     sleep(1);
        write(1, "C", 1);     sleep(1);
        write(1, "D", 1);
        return 0;

    } else {
        // parent
        write(1, "1234", 4);  sleep(1);
        write(1, "1", 1);     sleep(1);
        write(1, "2", 1);     sleep(1);
        write(1, "3", 1);     sleep(1);
        write(1, "4", 1);

        waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This program will print something like `1234ABCD1AB23CD4`.  The first `ABCD` will always appear as a group, and the first `1234` will also always appear as a group, but either one could be first; the second `ABCD` and `1234` might get mixed up together arbitrarily.

(Quiz question: why did I put the final `write(1, "\n", 1)` in the parent, *after* the `waitpid`?)

Comment: `PIPE_BUF` is only for pipes, it doesn't apply to files. Does it?

Comment: If I'm using a semaphore there isn't any problem with atomicity?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Indeed, if the writes are going to a file then the situation is completely different.  I'll think about how I could revise the answer to explain that.

Comment: @ABC It depends on how your code uses the semaphore and whether you care about writes from processes that aren't cooperating with your code.  Best to ask a whole new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX requires `write` syscall to be atomic in [2.9.7 Thread Interactions with Regular File Operations](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07):

> If two threads each call one of these functions [`write` is one of them], each call shall either see all of the specified effects of the other call, or none of them.

However, `write` is not required to write the whole requested amount. The maximum size of atomic writes depends on the filesystem. For pipes it is `PIPE_BUF`.

Note that `write` is a system call and these calls are much more expensive than regular calls. So, the popular method is to write into a buffer first and when the buffer is full or needs to be flushed immediately only then call `write` syscall. This is what C I/O library `fwrite` does for you.

Hence, you may like to prefer minimizing the number of `write` calls.

Comment: This is addressing a different issue entirely from the one OP is asking about.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is simply efficiency: Each call requires pushing the parameters onto the stack, then pulling them off in the function, then returning. This is all repeated unnecessarily when you call repeatedly.

Comment: There isn't any problem with atomicity?

Comment: There is no problem with atomicity unless you are writing to the same file at the same time from at least two different threads. If you don't know what that means, then you are probably not using threads, so no problem with atomicity.

Comment: Er, the system call overhead is hundreds to thousands of times more expensive than the stack push and pop.